Is this conjecture about twin primes known to be false?
I'm not sure if this has been investigated before. This is a kind of strong twin prime conjecture
Define a first twin prime as the lower of a twin prime pair, while a second twin prime is the upper of a twin prime pair.
The conjecture is: given any first twin prime $p>3$ there exist a second twin prime $q > p+2$ that is prior to the product of all first twin primes up to $p$ multiplied by $2$.
So, if $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ is the sequence of all first twin primes $< p$, then we'd have $p+2 < q < 2 \times a_1 \times \ldots \times a_n \times p$
This conjecture is stronger than the twin prime conjecture, so if it is false, then it can be disproved even if the twin prime conjecture is not yet solved.

Is the above conjecture false?


Sorry about my poor English.

I think that turn to computers for help is a wise option, Since the twin prime conjecture isn't solved yet.

If you say that $a_i$ is $i$-th lower twin prime, then your conjecture is $a_{n + 1} + 2 < 2\cdot a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n$ - is it correct? If yes, then I think first Hardy-Littlewood conjecture implies (hand-wavely) $a_n \approx C_2 \cdot n \cdot \log^2 n$, which is way stronger than your hypothesis. So disproving your conjecture is likely out of reach (unless there is small counterexample, but this is very unlikely).

I share this doubt , if a computer program confirms this upto $p\le 10^6$ , the conjecure should still be true and can probably even improved significantly.

@mihaild, yes it is $a_{n + 1} + 2 < 2\cdot a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_n$. So, from that I understand that if this is disproved then Hardy-Littlewood conjecture would be disproved??

Just to be clear, and using your notation, your conjecture is that for any $k$th twin prime pair $p_k,p_k+2$, there exists at least one larger twin prime pair $q-2,q$ that is smaller than $2\prod_1^k p_i$. Is that a fair understanding of your conjecture?

@KeithBackman, yes provided that $p_k > 3$, to be further clear we must have $q <2\prod_1^k p_i$.

Formally, first (there is also second) Hardy-Littlewood conjecture implies yours only for large enough $n$ - having say no twins in some range $[k, k!]$ contradicts your conjecture, but not their. But as your version is very much weaker (their imples $\forall \epsilon > 0 \forall^\infty n: a_{n + 1} < (1 + \epsilon) a_n$) and there are enough small twins to get right side bound very large, it seems not likely that their conjecture holds and yours fails.
